# Dynamic menu item in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I was wondering if there is a built in method in Drupal, to link to nodes created by a user. In my case, each and every user can create a node called "profile". I want to add a link in the menu, that links directly to that profile node.

I can do it by making a module that just checks for a link, e.g. mysite.com/?goTo=profile and then just write the sql to find the first node of type "profile" in the db and then just redirect to that, but surely drupal must have some kind of syntax or something by which you can specify that it must link to the first node of type x of user y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such API, neither in Code nor in the UI.

But as you said, it should be easy to write a small module for this. Looks like there was one at some point but has been abandoned: http://drupal.org/project/user_profile_node_integrator.

Could work like this:

- Register a menu path like /myprofile
- Add an access callback that checks if the user does have such a node. (You could add a second menu item that points to node/add/whatever if he doesn't and only shows in that case.)
- In your page callback, load the nid and either directly call node_view($nid) or forward to node/$nid.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a view (limit 1, filter on content type and user field) and use either [Insert View](http://drupal.org/project/insert_view) or [`views_embed_view()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/views_embed_view/6) to bring it in.

Comment: That's not a bad idea at all! :-) Would still prefer to link directly to the node (as it will show the correct link in the title bar) but I guess this could do the trick.